# Vimeo video full screen

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-player

my problem refers to the play button of a Vimeo video Iframe used it on an Android mobile device. When I press the play button the video goes in full screen mode automatically. There is the possibility to solve this problem? It occurs only using mobile devices. Thanks in advance